# pdflatex tex issue with section which contains underscore

Tags: characters, bookmarks

I have a tex file which is like this :

```
  \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={ 1,section,1, 200_project_title: , p1,
        1,subsection,1,Section A - Project Identification, p2,
        1,subsection,1,Section C - Basic or Applied Research,p3,
        3,subsection,1,Section D - Additional project information,p4
        }]{fixed_2010_2.pdf}
```

pdflatex fails to compile wherever there is undercore in section title

```
e.g  200_project_title:
```

It would be great if someone help me fine out a better way to pass section title without escaping those underscore and possibility handling other special characters which might mess up with compilation

thanks

**EDIT:** using
 `\begingroup \catcode'\_=12 \tableofcontents \endgroup`
  [image: screenshot]

**EDIT:** using 
in preamble : `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
and  for table of contents
`\begingroup \catcode'\_=12 \tableofcontents \endgroup`

[image: screenshot 2]

**Working one after you kind suggestions and answers:**
This working now for me (do not know any hazards yet) thank you for all your suggestions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[
  pdfpagelabels=true,
  pdftitle={Report Title},
  pdfauthor={sakhunzai},
]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, 
        linkcolor=blue
}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\_=12

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents 

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={ 1,section,1, 200_project_title: , p1,
        1,subsection,1,Section A - Project Identification, p2,
        1,subsection,1,Section C - Basic or Applied Research,p3,
        3,subsection,1,Section D - Additional project information,p4
        }]{fixed_2010_2.pdf}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Without a MWE this is untested but if  you don't have any underscores in math in section titles you can probably go `\begingroup \catcode'\_=12 \tableofcontents \endgroup` so `_` is a normal character while the toc file is being processed. (with a backtick not ' but I can't remember how to get that in this chat)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , thanks for your comments ,it fixed the issue partially e.g now I see  a dot in place of underscore

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Use *two* backquotes to delimit a code that contains backquotes: ``\begingroup\catcode`\_=12 \tableofcontents\endgroup``. Another way would be to write `200\_project\_title:` (which would work also with OT1 encoded fonts).

Comment: I just added `\begin{document}\catcode`\_=12` and rest of script , its working bookmarks look great but the Content area showing a dot , please check the attachedscreen shot , thanks for your direction

Comment: @sakhunzai you probably need to use a font encoding that has underscores in the underscpre position use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: @egreg  using `\_` is what I'd do, but the OP specifically asked to avoid quoting the underscores...

Comment: please check the attachment, section title under content area is not fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to avoid using `\_` for underscore you need to make it an ordinary character and use a font encoding that supports it so add

```
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to the preamble and then include the table of contents file the includes underscores with

```
\begingroup \catcode'\_=12 \tableofcontents \endgroup
```

If for some reason you are committed to `OT1` fonts and still want to avoid quoting `_` then you could instead use

```
\begingroup \catcode'\_=13 \def_{\_} \tableofcontents \endgroup
```

Comment: thanks @David Carlisle , first case works but removes underscore, please check the second attachment in question

Comment: I have accepted your ans. , plz check my edits if you have any further suggests regarding my working code.thanks

Comment: looks OK except that you globally redefined `_` to be an ordinary character (as opposed to just locally while the toc is read) which is OK so long as you don't need it for a math subscript anywhere (you can still get math subscripts using `\sb`)